# Retrieve all entries from Map<Integer, String> with keys in certain range

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I need to have a HashMap< Integer, String> which can serve fast operations for retrieving a list of all entries whose keys are in a certain integer range besides, getting values from map based on keys.

What `Map` implementation is suitable for these needs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `TreeMap`, which implements `NavigableMap` supplying a [subMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap%28K,%20boolean,%20K,%20boolean%29) method returning a view of the map with only keys in your range.  To get the values, of course you call `values()` on the result.

If you have an existing `Map` whose keys implement `Comparable`, you can construct a `TreeMap` from it by calling `new TreeMap(existingMap)`, but it will likely be more efficient to create it as a `TreeMap` from the start.

Comment: TreeMap<Integer, String> a; a.subMap(32, true, 36, true).entrySet(); // Is this the best way to go ? Will this be fast and efficient as well ?

Comment: I think that's likely as fast and efficient as you can get with standard libraries, and a lot easier than trying to roll your own.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for a [`NavigableMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html). However, you can't use `HashMap` to create one, because the map would have to be a `SortedMap`. Consider using `TreeMap` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`TreeMap` will provide a sorted list of keys. You would then need to trim the list to get your range of values.