# Need a Map for faster retrievals by key & for getting a list of entries with keys in some range

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I need a `Map<Integer,String>` with a major need to do fast retrievals of values by `key`. However I also have the need to retrieve `List` of all entries (`key`, `value` pairs) whose keys are in range (n1 to n2). However, No sorting required in the list. 
The map would hold atleast 10,000 such entries.

I initially thought of using `TreeMap` but that doesn't help with faster retrievals(O(log n) for get() operations). Is it possible to get a list of entries from HashMap whose keys are in range n1 to n2 ?

What would be my best bet to go with ?

Comment: You already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226634/retrieve-all-entries-from-mapinteger-string-with-keys-in-certain-range

Comment: Please define "fast retrievals" as in O(1)? Or is there some acceptable threshold

Comment: Salman is right.   Define 'fast'.   O(log N) is plenty fast for some things.   Why don't you just use TreeMap until you know that you have a real, testable performance issue.   Premature optimization is the root of all evil!

Comment: @John B: I did asked this but I do hope you realise that there is slight difference in the two questions. I have taken those answers into consideration and I'm extending that question by specifying my new problem.

Comment: For those who're willing to answer the question, I am looking for something closer to O(1) times for retrievals

Comment: Two maps?  One O(1) lookup and one with range capabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two implementations of `NavigableMap` (which allow you to retrieve sub-maps or subsets based on key ranges) are `TreeMap` and `ConcurrentSkipListMap`, both of which offer O(log n) access time.

Assuming you require O(1) access time as per a regular `HashMap`, I suggest to implement your own (inefficient) "key range" methods.  In other words, sacrifice the performance of the key-range operation for the improved access time you achieve with a regular `HashMap`.  There isn't really another way around this: `NavigableMap` methods are inherently dependent on the data being stored in a sorted fashion which means you will never be able to achieve O(1) access time.

Comment: hi.. could you clarify that whether the base of log in O(log n) is 10 or 2 ? I believe its 2 , right ?

Comment: It's base 2, but note that there's a constant multiplier difference between logs of different bases (log_2(4) = log_10(4)/log_10(2) for example), and because there's a constant multiplier difference, the two are big O equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

How close are the keys distributed? For 10000 elements, equally distributed over 20 000 possibilities like 0 to 19999, I could imagine a search for elements from 4 to 14 could be fine. You would miss at a 50% rate.

I wonder why TreeMap doesn't help with faster retrievals (O(log n) for get() operations)?

If you have Tree, with smaller values Left, and bigger ones right, you could return big parts of subtrees. Need it be Map and List?